# How to configure Testng eclipse plugin with arquillian

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, jboss-arquillian

I have arquillian set up here with some integration tests, but so far I'm running them with:

```
mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed
```

I would like to run and see the errors/successes on the Testng eclipse plugin. How do I do that?

I have tried to add a testng running config, selection a class to test, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Running TestNG from its Eclipse plugin or from maven are two different things!

The TestNG Eclipse plugin comes with its own version of TestNG - afaik, this isn't possible (without starting eclipse processes from you build process)

If reporting matters to you, you should have a look at ReportNG

To start a test run with your Eclipse Plugin (so you can see it in Eclipse's dedicated view), you have to select your test-class (or your test-xml) and use Run As -> TestNG test.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought, but my question is how do I properly config testng eclipse plugin to run arquillian integration tests (the same one that I've run through the mvn command that I have posted before)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding!
Could you provide information, what exactly didn't work? According to http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/#run_the_arquillian_test, it should be able to run in eclipse as well as with maven.

Comment: Sure, the problem (as far as I understood) is that I'm playing with WebArchive, deployed on 'wildfly-arquillian-container-managed'. Which I guess is run in another JVM. And the testng plugin is not being able to deploy it like the maven profile did.